# C# - Entity Framework: How to query ignoring case and diacritics

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I make a query on DB using Entity Framework (v7.0) ignoring case and diacritics?

I want to receive a parameter and ignore case and diacritics on the comparison.

I have tried:

```
expenses = expenses.Where(e =>                     
    e.Name.RemoveDiacritics().ToLower().Contains(dto.Name.RemoveDiacritics().ToLower())
);

// my extesion Method
static public string RemoveDiacritics(this string text)
{
    var normalizedString = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity: normalizedString.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = normalizedString[i];
        var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);

        if (unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }
     return stringBuilder
        .ToString()
        .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

And received the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Expense>()
    .Where(e => __userId_0 == e.UserId)
    .Where(e => e.Category
        .RemoveDiacritics().ToLower().Contains(__ToLower_1))' could not be translated. 
Additional information: Translation of method 'PersonalFinances.Shared.StringHelpers.RemoveDiacritics' 
failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, 
see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation 
explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. 
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Is there a right way of doing that??